# MySQL fails on: mysql "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded"

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, auth-socket

My local environment is:

- Fresh Ubuntu 16.04
- With PHP 7
- With installed MySQL 5.7

```bash
sudo apt-get install mysql-common mysql-server
```

---

When I tried to login to MySQL (via CLI):

```bash
mysql -u root -p
```

I came across an cyclic issue with 3 steps.

1. First was some socket issue

   ```bash
   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through    socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
   ```

   **Solution**: Restarting PC.

   Which led to another error:
2. With access denied

   ```bash
   ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.
   ```

   Possible issue? Wrong password for `root` user!

   **Solution**: [Reset root password with this RackSpace tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20190123093409/https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/).  With correct password and working socket, there comes last error.
3. Incorrect auth plugin

   ```bash
   mysql "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded"
   ```

   Here I stopped or somehow got to step 1. again.

Answer (score 458, accepted):

I got a solution!

**When resetting the root password at step 2), also change the auth plugin to `mysql_native_password`:**

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("") where User='root';
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';  # THIS LINE

flush privileges;
quit;
```

This allowed me to log in successfully!

---

### Full code solution

#### 1. First, run these bash commands

```bash
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop # stop mysql service
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & # start mysql without password
# enter -> go
mysql -uroot # connect to mysql
```

#### 2. Then run mysql commands => copy paste this to CLI manually

```
use mysql; # use mysql table
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("") where User='root'; # update password to nothing
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root'; # set password resolving to default mechanism for root user

flush privileges;
quit;
```

#### 3. Run more bash commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop 
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start # reset mysql
# try login to database, just press enter at password prompt because your password is now blank
mysql -u root -p
```

#### 4. Socket issue (from your comments)

When you see a *socket* error, a community came with 2 possible solutions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

(thanks to @Cerin)

Or

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld && chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

(thanks to @Peter Dvukhrechensky)

---

### Blind paths and possible edge errors

#### Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
mysql -uroot # "-hlocalhost" is default
```

Can lead to "missing file" or slt error.

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1
```

Works better.

#### Skip the socket issue

I've found many ways to create `mysqld.sock` file, change access rights, or symlink it. It was not the issue after all.

#### Skip the `my.cnf` file

The issue also was not there. If you are not sure, [this might help you](https://serverfault.com/questions/471372/etc-my-cnf-what-i-am-missing).

Comment: Thank you for this. This is also an excellent answer on how to reset mysql root pass so you might want to slightly edit the title to help it come up before we already run into the socket issue.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. How would you edit the title to keep origin message?
I understand the solution requires to reset password, but it does not solve the issue in the title. This is more complex failure of more points.
For root password reset, I'd go here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6401963/1348344

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Any idea why the plugin definition needs to be tweaked?

Comment: @matanster Not really, this is pure step-by-step trial-fail constructed. What OS do you use?

Comment: If you cant use mysql_safe here's a way to achieve this using systemctl 'set enviroment' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510184/change-mysql-root-password-on-centos7

Comment: Your mysqld_safe call is incorrect. You need to instead run: `sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld; sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

Comment: The init.d scripts don't work with the mysqld_safe process on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Worked for me after applying @Cerin's steps. I also recommend changing the second update statement to `update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';` so it doesn't unintentionally affect other users.

Comment: @Cerin Thanks for feedback. Can you edit the post and suggest changes? I'd be happy to accept them.

Comment: @Cerin Did you get my message? I'm not sure what exact lines to replace.

Comment: yeah, this solution it work for me, thank you. (same problem at macOS sierra 10.12.6, percona 5.7.18-16, installed by homebrew)

Comment: And be sure to re-establish a root password.

Comment: You might want to mark this answer as the correct one with greeny, since it indeed is correct :)

Comment: I am having same issue on windows how to fix that

Comment: Please add a posible solution of the socket issue to the answer. 
Like this one 
`mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld &&
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`
It may save someone's time

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated the answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Perfect Answer.!!!! Have been fiddling with the mysql config for too long, after resetting the root password.

Comment: Thanks! This was a super useful discussion. In the end I was not yet able to get my problem fixed with it, but most parts. Combining a couple of approaches I made a shell script that might come in handy for someone in the future: https://toxyl.github.io/mysql-innodb-recovery/

Comment: I was not able to stop mysql (step 3) when it was in safe mode (Ubuntu 16), and if you have multiple daemons running you will end up with issues (so be sure it's actually shutdown!).  To stop mysql in safe mode I had to run this command: 'mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown'

Comment: great work, 3 hours later i'm glad i found this answer, installing mysql server is fun because stuff like makes you question your profession

Comment: Indeed :D, I felt like quitting when I faced this for a week. I was just trying to store name and email in the user table.

Comment: I see the following under journalctl -xn, it seems that the authentication plugin and password are mutually exclusive?
"2019-05-07 14:06:14 9 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored."

Answer (score 60):

You can try as follows it works for me.

Start server:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Now, Go to sock folder:

```
cd /var/run
```

Back up the sock:

```
sudo cp -rp ./mysqld ./mysqld.bak
```

Stop server:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Restore the sock:

```
sudo mv ./mysqld.bak ./mysqld
```

Start mysqld_safe:

```
 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Init mysql shell:

```
 mysql -u root
```

Change password:

Hence, First choose the database

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

Now enter below two queries:

```
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('123456') where user='root';
mysql> update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';
```

Now, everything will be ok.

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit;
```

For checking:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

done!

`N.B, After login please change the password again from phpmyadmin`

Now check `hostname/phpmyadmin`

`Username: root`

`Password: 123456`

For more details please check [How to reset forgotten password phpmyadmin in Ubuntu](http://w3public.com/full-article/how-to-reset-forgotten-password-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu)

Comment: only this works for me! backup and restore socket is pretty smart

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) before the "done!" line in your answer when trying to login with 123456.

Comment: I solved doing the described steps in phpmyadmin (i.e. change password, change plugin). For some reason 'set authentication_string=password(...)' made it stop working (Error 1045 (28000): Access denied...).

Comment: Although this is a solution, whenever I restart my computer(ubuntu 20.04), I have to run all of these commands. Any permanent solution?

Answer (score 27):

The `mysql` command by default uses UNIX sockets to connect to MySQL.

If you're using MariaDB, you need to load the [Unix Socket Authentication Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) on the server side.

You can do it by editing the `[mysqld]` configuration like this:

```
[mysqld]
plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so
```

Depending on distribution, the config file is usually located at `/etc/mysql/` or `/usr/local/etc/mysql/`

If `unix_socket=OFF` is set in the same section, enable it by changing it to `unix_socket=ON` or this fix does not apply.

Comment: THIS one. All the other answers explain how to work around the error. This one explains how to RESOLVE it.

Comment: If you're on MariaDB 10.4.3 and later, the unix_socket auth plugin should be installed by default, but if you incorrectly reference it as plugin="auth_socket", instead of plugin="unix_socket" when updating your "user", you will receive this somewhat misleading message. My answer elaborates on how I messed this up.

Comment: If you're not on Debian or Ubuntu you might need to still load the plugin.
"In other systems, although the plugin's shared library is distributed with MariaDB by default as auth_socket.so, the plugin is not actually installed by MariaDB by default. There are two methods that can be used to install the plugin with MariaDB." [[https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/]]
So in my case I still needed to add the plugin for Manjaro

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql 5.7

- step 1: `sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld;`

  step 2: `sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld`

  step 3: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` & quit (use quit if its
  stuck )

login to mysql without password

- step 4: `sudo mysql --user=root mysql`

  step 5: `SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`

  step 6: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
  mysql_native_password BY 'root'`

now login with

- `mysql -u root -p <root>`

Comment: but at which step may i set the pass for root? because i tried ```$ mysql -u root -p``` but access denied yet.
```Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)``` I tried to input 'YES' password

Answer (score 9):

You can try these some steps:

Stop Mysql Service 1st 
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Login as root without password 
`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

After login mysql terminal you should need execute commands more:

```
use mysql;

UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('solutionclub3@*^G'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';

flush privileges;

sudo mysqladmin -u root -p -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
```

After you restart your mysql server
If you still facing error you must visit : [Reset MySQL 5.7 root password Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.solutionclub.in/reset-mysql-5-7-root-password-ubuntu-16-04-17-04.html)

Answer (score 7):

Try it:

```bash
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Work's in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone lands here after making the same mistake I did:

1. Switched to `plugin="mysql_native_password"` temporarily. Performed my tasks.
2. Attempted to switch back to the "auth_socket" plugin, but incorrectly referenced it as `plugin="auth_socket"` which resulted in `mysql "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded"`
3. Lacking a way to login to fix this mistake, I was forced to have to stop mysql and use `mysql_safe` to bypass authentication in order to switch to the appropriate plugin `plugin="unix_socket"`

Hopefully this saves someone some time if they receive the original poster's error message, but the true cause was flubbing the plugin name, not actually lacking the existence of the "auth_socket" plugin itself, which according to the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/):

> In MariaDB 10.4.3 and later, the unix_socket authentication plugin is installed by default, and it is used by the 'root'@'localhost' user account by default.

Answer (score 5):

I tried with and it works

```
use mysql; # use mysql table
update user set authentication_string="" where User='root'; 

flush privileges;
quit;
```

Comment: This worked for me on mysql version 8.0.22 for ubuntu 20.04+.
[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) says `PASSWORD()` function is removed from mysql 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (ubuntu 22.04):

**1) stop and remove mysql and related services**

```
sudo kill $(pgrep mysql)
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

**2) download APT repo**
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

**3) follow guide**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

**shortlist from the guide:**

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
```

inside the dialog leave settings as is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

it should be a dialog:
set ROOT password and leave auth setting as is.
I've tried to change it and got auth error.

Finally

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

Hope it will save your time, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

On macOS. If you don't use `brew` services, install it
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Stop MySQL:

```
brew services stop mysql@5.7
```

Start MySQL in safe mode:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL:

```
mysql -u root
```

Use `mysql` table:

```
use mysql;
```

Update the authentication:

```
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('') where User='root';
update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where User='root';
```

Flush the privileges and quit

```
flush privileges;
quit;
```

Restart MySQL:

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server stop
brew services start mysql@5.7
```

Answer (score -1):

**This may work**

CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';

Answer (score -1):

My cmd prompt was displaying the same error and sql installation command was stuck. Below commands worked for me.

Open a new terminal.
Terminate the current open mysql_secure_installation from first terminal,

```
sudo killall -9 mysql_secure_installation
```

Start the mysql client and you will move to sql prompt:

```
sudo mysql
```

Run the following SQL query:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'setYourPasswordHereWithinQuotes';

exit
```

Let's secure it by entering in cmd:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Whenever promoted for password, use the setYourPasswordHereWithinQuotes password you set in above sql query.

DONE!

Comment: This worked for me, anyways.

Answer (score -9):

You can try with the below commands:

```
hduser@master:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
hduser@master:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[ ok ] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does restarting the server solve the given error message?