# How to stop MySQL after running it using mysqld_safe?

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-5.7

I'm using `mysqld_safe` to be able to create a password for my `root` user (under Ubuntu 18.04, it is not asked on the installation).

To start MySQL, I have done:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables&
```

Now, the MySQL daemon is running and I can't stop it. Stopping it by killing the process prevent me to start another MySQL daemon because the previous one did not gave back the resources, resulting in errors like:

```
2018-10-31T14:50:40.238735Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2018-10-31T14:50:40.238815Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

So how can I stop the MySQL daemon when it have been started using `mysqld_safe`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. Maybe [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The command is:

```
$ mysqladmin shutdown
```

Comment: If your goal is to create a user, run `mysqld_safe` without putting it in the background (`&`) so you can just `^C` break it and go back to regular operation.

Comment: @jackalope I've noticed newer MySQL versions require ^\ (SIGQUIT).

Comment: Running this gave me access denied

Comment: on mac need to include user eg: `mysqladmin -u root shutdown` otherwise mysqladmin will try to use default user which is your current user.

Comment: I needed `sudo mysqladmin shutdown`

Answer (score 6):

The other answers did not work for me. Had to to this
`sudo killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld`

Comment: Never use this if you want to avoid database inconsistencies. Kill signal terminates MySQL instantly and if it has a running transaction that will prematurely end. QUIT signal (as @tadman wrote) avoids this situation and terminates MySQL properly.