# ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '0' is not loaded, table mysql.db probably corrupted

Tags: mysql, corruption, mysql-5.7

I have install the mysql 5.7.26 MAC OS version and import some tables from mysql 5.6, im not sure if this issue is related to this tables import.

The first time everything works fine but today, after shut down and start again the computer i have this error.

**ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '0' is not loaded**

I have try this solutions before create this question:

- [MySQL fails on: mysql "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded)
- [How To Fix MySQL ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' Is Not Loaded In MySQL 5.7+](https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-fix-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth_socket-is-not-loaded-in-mysql-5-7)

I check all databases and find this issue

```
$ sudo mysqlcheck --all-databases
[...]
mysql.user
warning  : 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
status   : OK
[...]
```

I check the table individually and looks fine, in `mysqld_safe` mode

```
CHECK TABLE mysql.user;
OK
```

This are the users i have in the `mysql.user` table in `mysqld_safe` mode.

```
[mysql> select Host, User from user;
+-----------+----------+
| Host      | User     |
+-----------+----------+
| %         | newuser  |
| 127.0.0.1 | root     |
| ::1       | root     |
| localhost | root     |
+-----------+----------+
```

In `mysqld_safe` mode, the `mysql.db` table is empty, im not sure if this is normal.

After all this testing, and the steps in the previous posts, i try to start the server and get this error log.

```
2019-04-29T07:55:12.121222Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-04-29T07:55:12.121283Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-04-29T07:55:12.121972Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-04-29T07:55:12.122063Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-04-29T07:55:12.123584Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.123629Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.123655Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.123682Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.123707Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124026Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124059Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124094Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124118Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124169Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124194Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124215Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124241Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124282Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124313Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124340Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124365Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124390Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124417Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124442Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124468Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124494Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124519Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124545Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124591Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124615Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124639Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124663Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124687Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124711Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124737Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124762Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124788Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124813Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124839Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124865Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.124891Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2019-04-29T07:55:12.131504Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-04-29T07:55:12.131596Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-04-29T07:55:12.232833Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /usr/local/mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-29T07:55:12.233473Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190429  8:55:12
2019-04-29T07:55:13.358154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 358642425
2019-04-29T07:55:13.358760Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-04-29T07:55:13.358805Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2019-04-29T07:55:13.358871Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-04-29T07:55:13.359316Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-04-29T07:55:13.359343Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2019-04-29T07:55:13.359360Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'keyring_file'
2019-04-29T07:55:13.359633Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2019-04-29T07:55:13.360312Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-04-29T08:18:36.081408Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-04-29T08:18:36.081770Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2019-04-29T08:18:36.081837Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26) starting as process 2805 ...
2019-04-29T08:18:36.088228Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2019-04-29T08:18:36.099373Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-04-29T08:18:36.099809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-04-29T08:18:36.099831Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-04-29T08:18:36.099859Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-04-29T08:18:36.100394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-04-29T08:18:36.100607Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-04-29T08:18:36.102471Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-04-29T08:18:36.115577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-29T08:18:36.135098Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.136644Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 358656043
2019-04-29T08:18:36.136692Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 358656052
2019-04-29T08:18:36.136716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-04-29T08:18:36.136733Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.454318Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-04-29T08:18:36.454376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-04-29T08:18:36.454563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-04-29T08:18:36.507314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.508403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.508440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.508800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-04-29T08:18:36.563837Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.26 started; log sequence number 358656052
2019-04-29T08:18:36.564162Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-29T08:18:36.564282Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.570440Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.573817Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-04-29T08:18:36.580847Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2019-04-29T08:18:36.581020Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.581075Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2019-04-29T08:18:36.581179Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.586150Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190429  9:18:36
2019-04-29T08:18:36.586976Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.587004Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.587027Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'::1' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.587051Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'newuser'@'%' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.590613Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_leap_second' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.590639Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_name' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.590654Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.590668Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition_type' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.590683Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.594257Z 0 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.641758Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 23. The table is probably corrupted
2019-04-29T08:18:36.641824Z 0 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 28
2019-04-29T08:18:36.642817Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_A
2019-04-29T08:18:36.642865Z 0 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
2019-04-29T08:18:36.643011Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.26'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Any idea where the issue come from?
Thanks in advance.