# how to set the mysql root password for the first time

Tags: mysql

I am on linux and I have never installed a database management system but when I type in the terminal `mysql --version`  I get `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`.

I can connect to the database without a password when I type `mysql`  without any password.

Meanwhile, I installed Adminer and I would like to use it alternatively phpmyadmin to manage my database but I can not connect myself I receive the following error in my browser `Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost'`.

I try all the methods found on google google to create a root password but I can not.

I tried the solutions proposed here:

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)
- [link2](http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/)
- [link3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)
- [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/46076838#46076838)

And many oder link.

How can I set a root password for mysql to use it in Adminer

Comment: Can you try to connect from the console using `mysql -u root -p` and then enter the configured password? If that works the configuration for Adminer is wrong. If that doesn't work, you need to show us the exact commands you've tried

Comment: I have already tried and I arrive so connected to me no matter what password I enter

Comment: Can you try this not using the root user on the machine? As that is probably what is bypassing the authentication

Comment: and which user should I use?

Comment: Any user which isn't root

Answer (score 6):

If you have never set a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. To set up a root password for the first time, use the mysqladmin command at the shell prompt as follows:

```
mysqladmin -u root password newpass
```

Comment: Have you stopped and started the MySQL service after you set password?

Comment: Yes several times. I even restart my pc

Comment: Have you opened the Command Prompt window using 'run as administrator' mode while set the password?

Comment: i'm using kali linux so i'm always in root

Comment: I used  `mysql_secure_installation`  to configure the root password but it still does not work i always get connected without password

Comment: when I type in the terminal `mysql --version`  I get  `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2.`

Answer (score 1):

I followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded). The initial Mysql Setup didnt work, so I did a password reset.
Mysql Version 5.7.38:

Warning: During this operation your anyone can access your MYSQL Server without password!

```
$> sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

```
[mysqld]          # add if not present
skip-grant-tables # add line
```

```
$> sudo mysql restart && mysql #should login with user root without password
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("YourNewPassword") WHERE user='root';
```

The following SQL was important:

```
mysql> UPDATE user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where user='root';
```

```
mysql> FLUSH privileges;
mysql> QUIT;
```

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  skip-grant-tables #remove line
```

Comment: It seems like the latest mysql dowsn't allow the PASSWORD() function any more

Comment: in Mysql 8 use `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'my password';` instead of `PASSWORD()`