# MySQL fails on: mysql “ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded” different case

Tags: mysql

[MySQL fails on: mysql "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded)

followed this and it gives 
"2019-09-15T06:21:16.719240Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-09-15T06:21:16.724724Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-09-15T06:21:16.758180Z mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists"

after the command "sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking & " .

I'm attaching the /var/log/mysql/error.log file.
[file](https://parmonov98.info/files/error.log)
I appreciate your help.

Comment: you need to kill the mysql process first, before running it in safe mode, use something like `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` or `sudo service mysql stop`

Comment: after killing it keeps me giving the same error. 
when used "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop" -> [ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.