# MySql login issue - auth_socket not loaded

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

Before I go any further, I will say that I have read many other posts and tried to fix this issue, but I just end up not being able to go anywhere because of more errors when trying to execute the commands.

I have no idea how the issue occurred, but when I try to do "mysql" to enter the MySQL environment, I get the following error: `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded`

I am running MariaDB in this version: `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.10-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as I don't really want to start over again. And as a quick side note, I can still access databases from my applications.

Comment: Have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded

Comment: Yep, and I just got more issues when trying to do so.

Comment: Ok, still having an issue so here is where I am stuck.

MariaDB [mysql]> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("") where User='root';
ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable

Answer (score 1):

On the command line:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
```

In MySQL:

```
flush privileges;
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("verysecret")`
```

Reference:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/