# MySQL: can't access root or command prompt

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) user, executed the following commands using [this tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/):

```
  807  sudo apt-get update
  808  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
  809  sudo ufw allow mysql
  810  systemctl start mysql
  811  systemctl enable mysql
  812  /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

The output from the last line is:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I get the same result without the `-p`:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Any ideas? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times, and the password I input at the prompts was my root password.

EDIT: I have tried both with and without `sudo`, I still get the same results

My Linux version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Bodhi Linux 5
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

My MySQL version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: Try and run mysql with `sudo` and if that works, follow the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @Tim even with sudo I get the same result

Comment: Even without -p?

Comment: Try sudo with mysql -u root -p

Comment: @Tim even without -p

Comment: @AnujVishwakarma I have, the result is still the same

Comment: @JessicaChambers your mySql version ?

Comment: @AnujVishwakarma here it is, I'll add it to the post too `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: You can check here (answer by Lahiru), see if it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y/42967789#42967789

Comment: @AnujVishwakarma I don't even have the log file, I think my installation must be going wrong somewhere? No errors were thrown during though: ` /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: For the log file try : sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: @AnujVishwakarma that returns nothing

Comment: Can you show us some logs or any error ? ..,
Try to stop the mySql service then. ,

sudo service mysql stop 
or

$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop ,
Start it in safe mode: ,

$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking ,


$ mysql -u root

Comment: Which ones would be of interest? when I try ` sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log ` I'm told that the file doesn't exist, and when I try ` sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysql/error.log ` I get no output at all. I have also tried ` sudo grep 'password' /var/log/mysql/error.log ` and I got about 20 lines like this: `2019-02-04T15:20:53.069385Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: `sudo grep 'password' /var/log/mysql/error.log` also gives these lines: `2019-02-04T15:20:53.072664Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'validate_password'
2019-02-04T15:20:54.839357Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-02-04T15:20:54.839366Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'`

Comment: Did you tried the above one, starting mysql in safe mode as I stated above ?

Comment: @AnujVishwakarma safe mode? Which one is that? I have tried every suggestion in this thread, nothing has worked so far

Comment: This one : 
Try to stop the mySql service then. , sudo service mysql stop or $ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop , Start it in safe mode: , $ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking , $ mysql -u root

Comment: @AnujVishwakarma safe mode gives me this: `2019-02-05T10:13:49.233122Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-02-05T10:13:49.247554Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-02-05T10:13:49.279705Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`

Comment: when I do `mysql -u root` I get : `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: So I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169345/6187682 and it gets stuck at `2019-02-05T10:20:18.704064Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Jessica, I tried the exact steps from the link you provided (rackspace). I am using 18.04 LTS. The step should be below when you invoke mysql. It worked perfectly fine for me. Also, in my case the mysql_secure_installation utility did not run automatic. So i had to invoke just "sudo mysql" and then updated the password for root.

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer, but even with sudo I still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I tidied up my system with:

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove mysql-server` then reinstalled it per the tutorial, the problem seems to have been resolved.