# How to reset mysql password without skip grant tables option?

Tags: mysql, change-password, reset-password

Is it possible to reset a `mysql` database's root password, without using `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` ?

Comment: Are you asking this for legal or illegal practice?

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) or some answers on stackoverflow, e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44647/117531) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490114/6248528) list a 2nd way (or actually the first, as in more correct, way). Both require you to have the (same) administrative privileges to do that.